# Unlock a locked user using batch class

Tags: apex

I am thinking or writing a batch class that would run once in every 3 days and check in the system if any user has password lock . If that is the case this class will go and reset the password.

I am able to find the "Login history" table where from I can get the information who is locked. But, I need to know: **is there any way to reset the password automatically as soon as the batch class runs**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tempted to say "you're doing it wrong".

First, check the lockout period:

[image]

With lockout period of 15 mins your user might end up not even have to wait for the admin's intervention / batch job execution.

Secondly - some Profiles can be set to "password never expires". It doesn't really solve the lockout problem but well - they would remember the password eventually, right?

I guess the real question is - what's your company policy when it comes to passwords & lockouts... it just feels bit off that "15-60 mins is too short, 3 days should be OK".

Answer (score 4):

Two possible approaches:

1. go to `Setup > Security Controls > Password Policies >  Maximum invalid login attempts`  and set  to `No Limit`. Using this approach effectively removes the need to build a process to unlock locked users. (Consider temporary lockout options too)

   **Alternatively**
2. create a batch class

   In the **Start method**

   Construct a query that approximates the following :

   ```
    SELECT Id 
    FROM User 
    WHERE Id IN ( SELECT UserId 
                  FROM LoginHistory 
                  WHERE Status = 'Password Lockout' AND LoginTime = TODAY )
   ```

   (Note : You will encounter  a SOQL error `field 'Status' can not be filtered in query call`. One solution would be to remove the Status filter from the query and instead defer the locked out filtering  to an an apex iteration ie more than one SOQL in your Start method )

   In the **execute method**

   call   `user.resetPassword()` on the user instance(s) passed into the execution context.